# WPF Binding with RelativeSource of Window Requires "DataContext" in Path?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

The following code works, but I'm curious as to why I need the Path to be prefixed with "DataContext"?  In most other cases, the path used is relative to DataContext.  Is it because I am using a RelativeSource?  Because the source is at the root level (Window)?

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter 
           Property="IsReadOnly"
           Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
           AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.IsReadOnly}"/>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're binding to the containing Window's DataContext, not to the Window itself.  Were you to put:

```
Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
       AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=IsReadOnly}"
```

This would bind to the `IsReadOnly` property of the Window, not its data context class.  Since [Window doesn't contain an IsReadOnly property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window_properties.aspx), this is obviously from a different class (most likely your ViewModel, if you're using MVVM, etc).